# Stiching multiple textures/frames together in OpenGL using a Kinect

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, kinect

I came across the following situation:

1. I have a Kinect camera and I keep taking frames (but they are stored only when the user presses a key).
2. I am using the [freenect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) library in order to retrieve the depth and the color of the frame (I am no interested in skeleton tracking or something like that).
3. For a single frame I am using the glpclview example that comes with the freenect [library](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect)

After retrieving the space data from the Kinect sensor, in the glpclview example, the current frame it is drawn like this:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_SHORT, 0, xyz);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_SHORT, 0, xyz);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_rgb_tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 640, 480, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgb);

glPointSize(2.0f);
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 640*480, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
```

where

```
static unsigned int indices[480][640];
static short xyz[480][640][3];
char *rgb = 0;
short *depth = 0;
```

where:

- **rgb** is the color information for the current frame
- **depth** is the depth information for the current frame
- **xyz** is constructed as :

  xyz[i][j][0] = j
  xyz[i][j][3](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) = i
  xyz[i][j][4](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect) = depth[i*640+j]
- **indices** is (I guess only) array that keeps track of the rgb/depth data and is constructed as:

  indices[i][j] = i*640+j

So far, so good, but now I need to render more that just one frame (some of them rotated and translated with a certain angle/offsets). How can I do this? 
I'ved tried to increase the size of the arrays and keep reallocationg memory for each new frame, but how can I render them? 
Should I change this current line to something else?

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 640, 480, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgb)
```

If so, to what values should I change 640 and 480 since now **xyz** and **rgb** is a contiguos pointer of 640x480x(number of frames)?

To get a better ideea, I am trying to get something similar to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Y4RQVpp-BY&feature=related) in the end (except the robot :D ).

If somewone has a better ideea, hint anything on how I should approach this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't as simple as allocating a bigger array.

If you want to stitch together multiple point-clouds to make a bigger map, you should look into the SLAM algorithms (that is what they are running in the video your link to). You can find many implementations at http://openslam.org. You might also look into an ICP algorithm (Iterative Closest Point) and the KinectFusion from Microsoft (and the open source KinFu implementation from PCL).

Comment: Thank you very much sir! It gave me a starting point! Also I came across another interesting solution here: http://manctl.com/products.html